# Time complexity of the word break recursive solution?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

What is the time complexity of the recursive solution to this in the code taken from: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/ :

```
// returns true if string can be segmented into space separated
// words, otherwise returns false
bool wordBreak(string str)
{
    int size = str.size();

    // Base case
    if (size == 0)  return true;

    // Try all prefixes of lengths from 1 to size
    for (int i=1; i<=size; i++)
    {
        // The parameter for dictionaryContains is str.substr(0, i)
        // str.substr(0, i) which is prefix (of input string) of
        // length 'i'. We first check whether current prefix is in
        // dictionary. Then we recursively check for remaining string
        // str.substr(i, size-i) which is suffix of length size-i
        if (dictionaryContains( str.substr(0, i) ) &&
            wordBreak( str.substr(i, size-i) ))
            return true;
    }

    // If we have tried all prefixes and none of them worked
    return false;
}
```

I'm thinking its n^2 because for n calls to the method, it worst case does (n-1) work (iterates over the rest of string recursively?). Or is it exponential/n!?

I'm having a tough time figuring out Big(O) of recursive functions such as these. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

The answer is **exponential**, to be precise `O(2^(n-2))`. `(2 power n-2)`

In each call you are calling the recursive function with length `1,2....n-1`(in worst case). To do the work of length `n` you are recursively doing the work of all the strings of length `n-1, n-2, ..... 1`. So T(n) is the time complexity of your current call, you are internally doing a work of `sum of T(n-1),T(n-2)....T(1)`.

Mathematically :

```
  T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) +.....T(1);
  T(1) = T(2) = 1
```

If you really don't know how to solve this, an easier way to solve the above recurrence is by just substitute values.

```
  T(1) = T(2) = 1
  T(3) = T(1) + T(2) = 1+1 =2; // 2^1
  T(4) = T(1)+ T(2) + T(3) = 1+1+2 =4; //2^2
  T(5) = T(1) + T(2) +T(3) +T(4) = 1+1+2+4 =8; //2^3
```

So if you substitute first few values, it will be clear that the Time complexity is `2^(n-2)`

Comment: I get how the recursive calls for worst case have been written, but have trouble visualising a string that actually causes the worst case. Is it that for this worst case to execute, every character prefix should be in dictionary, say for s = 'abcd', a,b,c,ab,ac etc but the last character,eg. d here should be absent to ensure that all worst case calls actually take place

Comment: What if we use a boolean array which stores whether the substring starting at the index is contained in dict? In such case no work will be done barring the first time and IMHO the time complexity will come down to n^2 which is total number of sub-strings. Pls let me know if this is correct.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, with two caveats. First, O(2^{n-2}) is the same as O(2^n), since 2^{n-2} = (2^n) / 4 and big-O munches leading coefficients. Second, your analysis ignores the cost of computing the substrings here with .substr and the cost of the dictionary lookups. Those turn out not to matter, but it's not obvious that that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

The short version:

> The worst-case runtime of this function is **Θ(2<sup>n</sup>)**, which is surprising because it ignores the quadratic amount of work done by each recursive call simply splitting the string into pieces and checking which prefixes are words.

The longer version: let's imagine we have an input string consisting of n copies of the letter `a` followed by the letter b. (we'll abbreviate this as `aⁿb`), and create a dictionary containing the words `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, ..., `aⁿ`.

Now, what will the recursion do?

- First, notice that none of the recursive calls will return true, because there's no way to account for the `b` at the end of the string. This means that each recursive call will be to a string of the form `aᵏb`. Let's denote the amount of time required to process such a string as T(k). Each one of these calls will fire off k smaller calls, one to each suffix of `aᵏb`.
- However, we also have to account for the other contributors to the runtime. In particular, calling `string::substr` to form a substring of length k takes time O(k). We also need to factor in the cost of checking if a prefix is a word. The code isn't shown here for how to do this, but assuming we use a trie or a hash table we can assume that the cost of checking if a string of length k is a word is O(k) as well. This means that, at each point where we make a recursive call, we will do O(n) work - some amount of work to check if the prefix is a word, and some amount of work to form the substring corresponding to the suffix.

Therefore, we get that

> T(k) = T(0) + T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(k-1) + O(k<sup>2</sup>)

Here, the first part of the recurrence corresponds to each of the recursive calls, and the second part of the recurrence accounts for the cost of making each of the substrings. (There are n substrings, each of which takes time O(n) to process). Our goal is to solve this recurrence, and just for simplicity we'll assume that T(0) = 1.

To do this, we'll use the "expand and contract" technique. Let's write out the values of T(k) and T(k+1) next to each other:

> T(k)   = T(0) + T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(k-1) + O(k<sup>2</sup>)
>
> T(k+1) = T(0) + T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(k-1) + T(k) + O(k<sup>2</sup>)

Subtracting this first expression from the second gives us that

> T(k+1) - T(k) = T(k) + O(k),

or that

> T(k+1) = 2T(k) + O(k).

How did we get O(k) out of the difference of two O(k<sup>2</sup>) terms? It's because (k + 1)<sup>2</sup> - k<sup>2</sup> = 2k + 1 = O(k).

This is an easier recurrence to work with, since each term just depends on the previous one. For simplicity, we're going to assume that the O(k) term is literally just k, giving the recurrence

> T(k+1) = 2T(k) + k.

This recurrence solves to T(k) = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - k - 1. To see this, we can use a quick inductive argument. Specifically:

> T(0) = 1 = 2 - 1 = 2<sup>0+1</sup> - 0 - 1
>
> T(k+1) = 2T(k) + k = 2(2<sup>k</sup> - k - 1) + k
> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 2k - 2 + k
> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - k - 2
> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - (k + 1) - 1

Therefore, we get that our runtime is **Θ(2<sup>n</sup>)**, since we can ignore the lower-order n term.

I was very surprised to see this, because this means that the quadratic work done by each recursive call does not factor into the overall runtime! I would have initially guessed that the runtime would be something like Θ(n · 2<sup>n</sup>) before doing this analysis. :-)

Comment: I think you meant T(0) = 1 = 2 - 1 = 2^(0+1) - 0 - 1 instead of T(0) = 1 = 2 - 1 = 2^0 - 0 - 1

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer should actually be `O(2^(n-1))`. You can see a proof as this as well as a worst-case example here:

https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/discuss/169383/The-Time-Complexity-of-The-Brute-Force-Method-Should-Be-O(2n)-and-Prove-It-Below

Answer (score 1):

One intuitive way I think about the complexity here is, how many ways are there to add spaces in the string here or break the word here ?

for a 4 letter word: 
no of ways to break at index 0-1 * no of ways to break at index 1-2 * no of ways to break at index 2-3 = 2 * 2 * 2.

2 is there to signify the two options => you break it, you don't break it

O(2^(n-1)) is the recursive complexity of the wordbreak then ;)